# Como decompor o significado dum título como «Oficial 4º Ajudante»?

Tags: gramática, nomes

Estou a tentar entender a gramática na frase «Oficial 4º Ajudante», que é o nome da função que um certo funcionário exerce num certo cartório ou conservatória. Entendo que a pessoa é um oficial, sim, e entendo que é um ajudante. Mas como interagem as três palavras nesta frase? Será que «4º Ajudante» é uma frase nominal que age como adjectivo, esclarecendo «Oficial»: «[um] Oficial [que é um/o] 4º Ajudante»?

Comment: Eu acho que sim. Espero que venha alguém com conhecimento gramatical e nos explique numa boa resposta. :)

Comment: Acho que você precisa dizer em que lugar. Porque, por exemplo, se olhar o Cabo Verbe, esse 4º se refere a um nível. Veja bem o quadro nesse documento: enquadramento dos cargos dos oficiais ajudantes. https://ofcv.cv/images/Documentos-PDFs/Legislacao/bo_07-03-2018_16.pdf Existem oficiais de 1 a 4 (nível de salário).

Answer (score 1):

Bom, vamos começar pelo princípio... "Oficial 4o Ajudante" não é uma frase, é somente um título, um cargo. Neste caso, para ter uma frase completa, você precisaria do predicado (verbo + complementos)

O que deixa esse título um pouco complicado é que o nome real é "Oficial Ajudante", e o "4o" se refere ao nível dessa posição dentro do grupo de Oficiais Ajudantes. Isso é uma herança das patentes militares portuguesas (e.g. primeiro oficial, segundo oficial, etc.)

Por motivos de clareza, muitos cartórios vem optando pela denominação Oficial Ajudante nível X nos concursos. Uma outra comparação seria com uma estrutura empresarial, em que você tem profissionais de nível júnior, pleno e sênior dentro de uma mesma posição (e.g. Analista de Logística Júnior, Gerente de Produção Pleno...)